# A method to hand paint individual faces, like Minecraft

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I am currently looking for a method to easily hand paint Minecraft styled characters, and seemingly the best way to do this would be to paint subdivided cubes.

Would there be any method in the texture painting tab to easily do this?

Comment: you  could use a low resolution texture and set the image texture to 'closest' in the shader editor, so when painting the mesh, you'll do it per pixel on the texture.

Answer (score 1):

There's a *Paint Mask* option in *Texture Paint* mode, once enabled, select the faces you want to paint on with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>LMB</kbd> (and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>LMB</kbd> to unselect) or with the lasso <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd> (and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd> ton unselect):

[image]